# chowning each home user to itself recursively

Tags: shell, directory, chown

Okay so I have about 100 directories in my home folder each owned by the home user itself. Sometimes I have to manually replace some files as root so the permissions are disturbed and some files are no longer owned by that user. To fix this, I always have to use the following command within the home directory:

```
chown -R user:user user/
```

Now I'm looking at some shortcut because I can't do this for all the 100 users out there.

I'm wondering what would be done by:

```
chown -R *:* *
```

Comment: `cd home; for i in * do chown -R ${i}:${i} ${i}; done`

Comment: @JennyD You missed a semicolon after the `*`

Comment: @val0x00ff Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full answer would be

1) Open a file like  `vi chown_homedirs`

2) Put in the next code

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home &&    
for h in *
  do 
    chown -R "$h:$h" "$h"; 
  done
```

3) Save the file

4) `chmod +x chown_homedirs`

5) run `./chown_homedirs`

NOTE: If user directories have spaces in them you always need to quote the expansion. If you don't quote the expansion things might fail and pose you to unexpected results.

Comment: I wonder why this is needed and what it does shopt -s extglob

Comment: @Asad Moeen http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) to get the user and group ownership of a file then use these to update the files, something like

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home
for file in *
do
    user=$(stat -c %U "$file")
    group=$(stat -c %G "$file")
    echo chown -R "$user":"$group" "$file"
done
```

This deals with the situation where the owner/group/directory aren't all the same.  Obviously remove the echo if it out tests ok for you.

Comment: Use caution when writing scripts that cd to a target and perform operations.  Consider this script is run by an administrator on a server where /home is in a bad state and the administrator is currently in /var.  Everything in var would be chown -R root:root.  I would recommend iterating directly on `/home/*` or using something like `if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo Failed to cd to /home.  Exiting!; exit 1; fi`.

Comment: @KyleSmith: There are lots of things wrong with the script from the POV of being complete, it's really just demonstrating the use of `stat` rather than blindly assuming the ownership of the files.

Comment: @KyleSmith Bash uses `[[]]` keyword for testing. `[` test command is used only if you are writing for `!sh`. Also you should not be needing to check the status code, instead  `! cd /home && echo "failed" >&2; exit 1`

Comment: @Iain:  Understood, just want to make sure OP or anyone else considering a script is thinking of the caveats.

Comment: @val0x00ff:  Using `&&` *is* checking the status code.  My code is just a more verbose way of accomplishing the same.